# Achieving a delay effect by adding arrays c

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

Say I have 2 arrays, buffer1 and buffer 2. Both of these arrays have the exact same data and are the same length. I could add the results of these 2 arrays together like so:

```
for (n=0; n<100; n++)
    buffer3[n] = (buffer1[n] + buffer2[n]);
```

Say each of these buffers contains the data points that make up a sine wave. If I was able to shift the points in 1 array by 180 degrees and add them again, this would result in cancellation right?
And I think points in between 90 and 180 degrees would result in the resultant sine wave becoming lower in amplitude until it eventually cancels out - a filter effect if you like.

I tried to do this with the following code but the problem is when `n` is at 51 then `[n + 50]` is a value of 101...which is invalid right?

```
for (n=0; n<100; n++)
    buffer3[n] = (buffer1[n] + buffer2[n+50]);
```

I think a circular buffer or something like that would need to be employed here but im not sure how I would integrate it into the code above, I understand its to do with `n` going out of bounds but just can't get my head around how to achieve what I want; is it possible?

Comment: Would modular arithmetic be helpful when you do the `n+50`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int offset = 50;
for (n=0; n<100; n++){                   
        buffer3[n] = (buffer1[n] + buffer2[(n+offset)%100]);
```

Comment: yes it works thanks! would you mind explaining why it works, i have seen modulus used for seeing if numbers are odd or even but i dont really know whats happening here? thank you

Comment: val%100 will only output a value from 0 thru 99. It returns the remainder of dividing val by 100. So if val= 105 then remainder is 105-100 = 5. If val was 305, then remainder is 305-100-100-100 = 5 (again). val = (val/100)*100 + val%100; (with divide being integer divide with no rounding).

Comment: Once upon a time, it would have been reasonable to have a second index `n1` initialized to 50 and then do `n1++; if (n1 >= 100) n1 = 0;` but these days, the conditional probably stalls the pipeline compared to simply doing the unconditional modulus operation so what's written is likely better.